# Replace values based on occurances

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace the number of occurrences in a data frame with the values in the x column, regardless of the number of occurrences. How can I do this?

Data structure:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(x = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60), `04:00` = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `04:10` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `04:20` = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `04:40` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    x = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), `04:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `04:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `04:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `04:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `04:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `case_when` by looping `across` the columns other than 'x', create the logical condition where value of that column is not equal to x, then return the 'x' value or else the column value

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(across(-x, ~ case_when(. != 0 ~ x, TRUE ~ .)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
      x `04:00` `04:10` `04:20` `04:30` `04:40`
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1    10       0      10       0       0       0
2    20       0       0       0       0       0
3    30       0      30       0       0       0
4    40      40       0      40       0       0
5    50       0       0       0       0       0
6    60       0       0       0       0       0
```

---

Or may simplify as

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(-x, ~ (. > 0) * x))
```

---

Or use `base R`

```
df1[-1] <-  (df1[-1] > 0)* df1$x[row(df1[-1])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Base method with `apply` and `ifelse`:

```r
apply(df, 2, function(i) ifelse(i!=0, df$x, 0))
```

```
      x 04:00 04:10 04:20 04:30 04:40
[1,] 10     0    10     0     0     0
[2,] 20     0     0     0     0     0
[3,] 30     0    30     0     0     0
[4,] 40    40     0    40     0     0
[5,] 50     0     0     0     0     0
[6,] 60     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply this

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, across(!x, ~ as.logical(.) * x))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
      x `04:00` `04:10` `04:20` `04:30` `04:40`
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1    10       0      10       0       0       0
2    20       0       0       0       0       0
3    30       0      30       0       0       0
4    40      40       0      40       0       0
5    50       0       0       0       0       0
6    60       0       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use use apply. We can use a simple function that takes in a vector and replaces any non-zero element of that vector with that vector's `x` value, then we apply that function to each row of the dataframe.

Only tricky thing is the apply output isn't in the format we want, but a quick transpose and coerce to dataframe gets us back in business.

```
apply(X = x, MARGIN=1, FUN = function(r){r[r>0] = r['x']; r}) %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

`LC-datascientists` solution is probably better. `ifelse` can sometimes be problematic, but should be good here. Plus, it's going to be wayyyyy faster than my solution on large datasets since it's applied over columns rather than rows.